# Execute and wait for results C program and Python script

Tags: python, c, wait, execution

My today's task is to create a Python script (say **A.py**) which can do the following things:

- Start a C program (say **CProg**) passing some params
- Start another Python script (say **B.py**) passing other params
- Join/Wait until **B.py** has finished
- Send a SIGINT to **CProg**
- Iterate (this won't be a problem at all I think :P)

Since I'm pretty new in developing Python scripts and my mind is quite full of C/C++ thread/join/execve/... I'd like to ask you if there's a proper way to accomplish my task. I've read some related topics on SO (some talk about PIPEs or Execl) but I'm not sure what to use yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: LOL ... have you given A.py an attempt at all? if you are used to threads in C the principles are the same in any language... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies has a bunch of starting point answers for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys

params = [...]
for param for params:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/CProg', param.., param..])
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'B.py', param.., param...])
    os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGINT)
    proc.wait()
```